# How to convert a date into a text in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets-api

I would like to convert a date into a text like:

194408100800

Where the date is 19440810 and the time 0800.

If possible I would like the translation to be
On August 10, 1944 at 08h00 the following happened.

Any idea how to do it?

I would appreciate knowing the coding required.

Thanks

Serge Angeric

Comment: it looks like you are trying to use App Script, and you are just starting with Google Sheets. Start here - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets . you should find out most of the answers you are looking for.

Comment: What have you tried so far?